# How to list android system files in a listbox?

Tags: android, file, delphi, system, firemonkey

i need the right way to list Android system files in a ListBox, i used this idea but it didnt work 
plz help, many thanks in advance

```
  ` var
   fs: TFileStream;
   fn: string;
   sr: TSearchRec;
   I : integer;
   begin
    I := 0;
   if FindFirst('data/data/com.android.browser/*.*', faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then
   begin
    repeat
    ListBox1.Items.Add('data/data/com.android.browser/' + sr.Name);
     Inc(I);
      if I = 7 then Break;
      until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
      FindClose(sr);

 end;
  if I < 7 then
   begin
  if FindFirst('data/data/com.android.browser/*.*', faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then
   begin
     repeat
       ListBox1.Items.Add('data/data/com.android.browser/' + sr.Name);
       Inc(I);
       if I = 7 then Break;
       until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
       FindClose(sr);
      end;
      end;`
```

Comment: So you could have started telling you used Delphi. What does not work? What happens instead? Is your app com.android.browser? If not you have no access in that directory.

Comment: You have to use `System.IOUtils` classes for doing cross-platform I/O in Delphi. See [TDirectory.GetFiles](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles)

Comment: com.android.browser is the default browser in android, i couldn't list the files in that Dir, and yes i used  System.IOUtils classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles).

```
uses System.Types, System.IOUtils, System.SysUtils;

procedure AddFiles(MyListBox: TListBox);
var
  SDA: TStringDynArray;
  I, II: Integer;
  LBI: TListBoxItem;
begin
  SDA := TDirectory.GetFiles(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + System.SysUtils.PathDelim,'*.dat');

  for I := Low(SDA) to High(SDA) do
   begin
     II := MyListBox.Items.Add(ExtractFileName(SDA[I]));
     LBI := MyListBox.ListItems[II];
     LBI.ItemData.Detail := SDA[I];
   end;
end;
```

Comment: i don't know how to use it !, I'll really appreciate little explanation, many thanks

Comment: it didn't work!, the listbox is empty, perhaps there is a mistake in calling the procedure?
AddFiles(MyListBox);

Comment: Maybe it did work and the directory is empty of the file type you searched for.

Comment: im still a beginner in dlephi, how to specify which file type to look for?, and how to get access to 'com.android,browser' Dir?, many thanks for you help

Comment: *.dat is the wildcard string to search for. So .dat is the extension. Here is the list of path functions to get the directory: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.IOUtils.TPath